# How Could i Show Drawer Navigator and Tab Navigator Together?

Tags: android, react-native

How Could i Show Drawer Navigator and Tab Navigator Together?

It only shows one of them by changing the order of

```
 <TabNavigate /> ,
 <AppDrawerNav />
```

in this part

```
export default class App extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <TabNavigate /> ,
  <AppDrawerNav />

   );
 }
}
```

***************** Here is the Full code *************************

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView, ScrollView, 
Dimensions, Image } from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator, DrawerItems, createMaterialTopTabNavigator } 
from 'react-navigation';
import HomeScreen from './Screens/HomeScreen';
import SettingScreen from './Screens/SettingScreen';
import SwitchesScreen from './Screens/SwitchesScreen';
import SencesScreen from './Screens/SencesScreen';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
   return (
  <TabNavigate /> ,
  <AppDrawerNav />

    );
 }
}

const CustomDrawerContents = (props) => (
  <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <View style={{ height: 150, backgroundColor: 'white', alignItems: 
  "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
  <Image source={require('./Images/hotel.png')} style={{ height: 120, width: 
120, margin: 20 }} />
</View>
 <ScrollView>
   <DrawerItems{...props} />
 </ScrollView>
</SafeAreaView>
)

const AppDrawerNav = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
  Settings: SettingScreen
 }, {
 contentComponent: CustomDrawerContents,
 drawerWidth: 200,
 contentOptions: {
  activeTintColor: 'orange'
   } 
  }
 )

 const TabNavigate = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
 Switches: SwitchesScreen,
 Sences: SencesScreen
 },
 {
 tabBarPosition: "bottom",
 swipeEnabled: false,
 tabBarOptions: {
  activeTintColor: 'blue',
  inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
  showIcon: true,
  style: {
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  },
  indicatorStyle: {
    backgroundColor: 'teal',
    height: 0
  }
  }

  })
```

i Found some Similar questions previously asked but non of them worked for me

i want both drawer and tabs in all pages

i'm beginner , please help me

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a UI what you want to do. According to your question it seems like you want to set NavigationDrawer and TabNavigation (Like Instagram).

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple sample code:

First, you need to install.: react-navigation

```
$ npm i react-navigation --save
```

and here is the *App.js* sample:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

class InitialScreen extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>Home</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

class ConfigScreenApp extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={[styles.container, {backgroundColor:'green'}]}>
                <Text>Config App Screen</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

class ConfigScreenProfile extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={[styles.container, {backgroundColor:'yellow'}]}>
                <Text>Config Profile Screen</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const ConfigScreen = createDrawerNavigator({
    ConfigScreenApp:{
        screen:ConfigScreenApp
    },
    ConfigScreenProfile:{
        screen:ConfigScreenProfile
    }
});

const Navegador = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen:InitialScreen
  },
  Config: {
    screen:ConfigScreen
  }
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex:1,
        justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems:'center',
        marginTop:20
    }
});

export default Navegador;
```

that's all..